# Can not debounce action within other action in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lodash, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to debounce anything within an Action, it gets swallowed in one way or another...

Take this (pseudo) code:

```
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const actions = {
  debounceSomeLogging ({ dispatch }, text) {
    console.log("Outside debounced function.");
    debounce(function() {
      console.log("Inside debounced function.");
      dispatch("doRealThing");
    }, 1000);
  },

  doRealThing({ commit }) {
    // Whatever
  }
}
```

When I call the action, I see the `Outside debounced function`, but I can not see the other logging and the other action does not get triggered.

Anyone have experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: debounce does not run your function but creates a new one which is when called delays the invoking of your inner function. So you need to assign the return value of debounce and call it from somewhere...

Comment: Okay, that seemed to be the problem. Thank you a lot, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) pointed out in a comment, the `debounce` function does not call the inner function. So you need to call the debounce again, like so:

```
debounce(function() {
  console.log("Inside debounced function.");
  dispatch("doRealThing");
}, 1000)();
```

So, in short, it should look like this:

`debounce(...)()` instead of like this  `debounce(...)`.

Answer (score 14):

This should definate work

```
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const actions = {
  debounceSomeLogging: debounce(({ dispatch }, text) => {
    console.log("Inside debounced function.");
    dispatch("doRealThing");
  }, 1000),

  doRealThing({ commit }) {
    // Whatever
  }
}
```